# How do I escape a keyword which is a command in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, heredoc

Inside my shell script I have

```
#!/bin/bash
var1=$1
var2=$2
cat<<new_script<<EOF
...some code...
for i in `find / -perm 6000 -type f`; do chmod a-s $i; done
mkdir $var1
...some code...
EOF
```

I have tried a lot of things, but I am not able to escape the "find" command.
Instead of writing it to the new_script, when I run this shell script, it just runs the find command in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Quote `EOF` with single quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >>new_script <<'EOF'
...some code...
for i in `find / -perm 6000 -type f`; do chmod a-s $i; done
...some code...
EOF
```

Comment: Can you explain what changes does putting 'EOF' do to make it work?

Comment: Without single quotes, behavior is variables are interpolated, commands in backticks are evaluated, etc. This can be disabled by quoting any part of the label, which is then ended by the unquoted value. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells).

Comment: I need to use variables as well. I have made the edits.

Comment: Replace `'EOF'` by `EOF` and `\`find / -perm 6000 -type f\`` by `\$(find / -perm 6000 -type f)`.